# JavaFX populate tableview with a OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8

to populate a table is easy when you populate it with data from one class, but what is when I want to populate it with data from a OneToMany relationship?

for example:

Class Person:
Id, firstname, lastname, 
cars(cars have a onetomany relationship with Class Cars, so one person can have one or more cars)

Now, if a person got two cars, how can I add this to a table?

It should look something like this:

```
ID  |  firstname  |  lastname  |  vehicleBrand(from cars)
==============================================
1   |  jack       | jackson    |  crysler
----------------------------------------------
    |             |            |  bmw
----------------------------------------------
2   |  sally      | jackson    |  ford
```

If I have the observable list from Person I can populate the person data like this:

```
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("firstName")
);
```

but something like:

```
vehicleBrandCol.setCellValueFactory(
new PropertyValueFactory<Cars,String>("vehicleBrand")
);
```

or

```
vehicleBrandCol.setCellValueFactory(
new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("vehicleBrand")
);
```

does not work.

Edit:
The answer below works for one brand. If I try to add all I tried it by using a loop like this:

```
for (Car aCars : cars) {
                return new SimpleObjectProperty<>(aCars.vehicleBrand());
            }
```

But the loop does not loop?! (I printed the size of cars and it is not 1)

Comment: It doesn't loop because you are exiting the method the first time you hit the `return` statement.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense ^^ should I make a List of the SimpleObjectProperty and return this?

Comment: No, in this case it won't work because your column should contain `String` values not `List` values.

Comment: Ok, I work a little bit on this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be part of what you are looking for, you can do this:

- Now I'm supposing you have the two classes `Person` and `Car`.
- The class `Person` has an `ArrayList<Car>` of cars.
- The class `Person` has also a method `getCars()` which returns this person's collection (the `ArrayList`) of cars.

Now to get the brand from your `Car` class displayed in the `TableView` of persons you can set the `CellValueFactory` as follows:

```
vehicleBrandCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Person,String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Person, String> param) {
                ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
                cars = param.getValue().getCars();
                if(cars!=null && !cars.isEmpty()) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(cars.get(0).getBrand());
                }
            }
        }
);
```

The `param.getValue()` method returns the `person` passed as a parameter.

Notice that in this example I'm returning(displaying) only the first car brand from the collection of cars of the current person, you can try to adapt this example to your case.

> Ok, that makes sense ^^ should I make a List of the
>   SimpleObjectProperty and return this?

No you can't do this because you are declaring a column that should contain `String` objects not `List` objects.

What you can do is create custom cells that would allow you display all of the `Car` brands of a each `Person` instance, you can take a look at [this example](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/) to get a grasp of Cell rendering, and here is my example that could help you in your case:

First set the type of the content of cells in `vehicleBrandCol` to `ArrayList<String>`:

`private TableColumn<Person, ArrayList<Car>> vehicleBrandCol;`

Then set the `CellValueFactory` as follows:

`vehicleBrandCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, ArrayList<Car>>("cars"));`

and then you'll need custom cells to display data (Cars) contained within this `ArrayList`, so set the `CellFactory` as follows:

```
vehicleBrandCol.setCellFactory(column->{
            return new TableCell<Person, ArrayList<Car>>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(ArrayList<Car> item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if(item==null || empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        VBox vbox = new VBox();
                        for(Car car : item) {
                            Label lbl = new Label(car.getBrand());
                            vbox.getChildren().add(lbl);
                        }
                        setGraphic(vbox);
                    }
                }
            };
        });
```

Notice that I'm creating a `VBox` and using Labels, you can use whatever `Node` you like, for example you can use a `ListView`, or a `GridPane` and set them as graphic for the `Cell`.

Comment: Thanks, that works! but if I try to loop over the List to get all brands the loop does not loop. I edited the code I tried to my question.