# JavaFX OneToMany(1:n) In TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX and want to create a TableView. 
I've chose the following example with the class Person which contains an ArrayList.
The OneToMany-relation(1:n) should be displayed like this.

```
╔════╤════════════════════╤════════════════════╗
║    │        name        │         car        ║
║ id ├──────────┬─────────┼──────────┬─────────╢
║    │  forname │ surname │   brand  │  model  ║
╠════╪══════════╪═════════╪══════════╪═════════╣
║  0 │ John     │ Doe     │ Audi     │ A3      ║
║    │          │         │ VW       │ Golf3   ║
╟────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────┼─────────╢
║  1 │ Jane     │ Doe     │ BMW      │ i5      ║
╚════╧══════════╧═════════╧══════════╧═════════╝
```

### Person class:

```
class Person
{
    private SimpleStringProperty forname;
    private SimpleStringProperty surname;
    private List<Car> cars;

    public Person(String forname, String surname, List<Car> cars)
    {
        this.forname.set(forname);
        this.surname.set(surname);
        this.lehrveranstaltungen = lehrveranstaltungen;

    }
    public Person()
    {
        this("","",new ArrayList<Car>());
    }

    public String getForname()
    {
        return forname.get();
    }
    public String getSurname()
    {
        return surname.get();
    }
    public List<Car> getCars()
    {
        return cars;
    }
}
```

The car class looks similar to this

#### What is the simplest approach to do this ?

The main problem I have 
is to create a subrow for every car object.
How do I have to design the CellFactory for the carColumn ? 
I tried this example [JavaFX populate tableview with a OneToMany relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509031/javafx-populate-tableview-with-a-onetomany-relationship)
But how can I populate the subcolumns of car with the attributes of the car class? It just works with 1 attribute. Do I have to declare the attribute of the car to every subcolumn ?

Comment: The simplest approach would just be to use a cell factory and set the text of the cell to  `String.join("\n", carBrands)` (and similarly for the other columns). You don't actually get any guarantee that the brands and models will line up exactly, but it should work. A more complex approach would be to use a `TreeTableView`, though it would be difficult in this case to fit the object model to the object model a `TreeTableView` expects. There's no built-in "row span" in JavaFX table views (or similar controls).

Comment: TreeTableView is a possibility but isn't there any way to create a table like I showed ? Your first solution is not really what I want to do. The Example I posted did it with 1 column. But I need this column with subcolumns which display 1 attribute of the object each.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear how the solution I suggested is different to what you're looking for: it would look just like the image you showed. Can you clarify the difference?

Comment: Oh sorry yes the first solution is possible. Can I use a VBOX there instead of making a new line ?

Comment: That should work too.

Comment: Okay thank you I will try it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *simplest* approach is to make the data value for both the "Brand" column and the "Model" column the list of cars; then use a cell factory to set the text for the cell to the appropriate values from each car, separated by newline characters.

This has some drawbacks: there's no absolute guarantee the height of all lines in a list cell with multiline text will be equal, so you're not completely guaranteed that these will line up exactly. I think it will work ok for this use case. If you wanted more control, you could create a `VBox` which you use as the cell's graphic, and populate it with individual labels, once for each car. That way you could control the height of the label if you needed; potentially you could style the label to give the effect of a border, so it really looked like "subcells".

Additionally, these cells won't update if the data are changed while the table is displayed, though this is more a consequence of your use of a plain `List<Car>` for the cars. This can be fixed with use of appropriate `ObservableList`s, perhaps with extractors if needed.

Finally, this just uses a single cell to render the each list of car brands and car models, so you can't select an individual brand or model.

The simple solution looks like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewWithList extends Application {

    // Cell implementation used later to create cells with multiline text
    // from a cell item that is a List
    public static class MultilineCell<S, T, U extends List<T>> extends TableCell<S, U> {

        // function mapping each element of the list to a string
        private final Function<T, String> textMapper ;

        public MultilineCell(Function<T,String> textMapper) {
            this.textMapper = textMapper ;
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(U items, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(items, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {

                // map each element of the list to a string, and join them with
                // a new line between each
                setText(
                    items.stream()
                        .map(textMapper)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
                );
            }
        }
    }


    // Utility method to create a table column with a given title and function mapping
    // the row value to a property to be used as the data for cells in that column
    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col  ;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableColumn<Person, List<Car>> brandCol = column("Brand", 
                person -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(person.getCars()));

        TableColumn<Person, List<Car>> modelCol = column("Model",
                person -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(person.getCars()));

        brandCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new MultilineCell<>(Car::getBrand));
        modelCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new MultilineCell<>(Car::getModel));        

        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Person, Void> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Person, Void> carCol = new TableColumn<>("Car");
        table.getColumns().add(nameCol);
        table.getColumns().add(carCol);

        nameCol.getColumns().add(column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty));
        nameCol.getColumns().add(column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty));

        carCol.getColumns().add(brandCol);
        carCol.getColumns().add(modelCol);


        Car a3 = new Car("Audi", "A3");
        Car golf = new Car("VW", "Golf GTI");
        Car i5 = new Car("BMW", "i5");

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("John", "Doe", a3, golf),
                new Person("Jane", "Doe", i5)
        );

        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static class Car {

        private final String brand ;
        private final String model ;

        public Car(String brand, String model) {
            this.brand = brand;
            this.model = model;
        }

        public String getBrand() {
            return brand;
        }

        public String getModel() {
            return model;
        }
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();

        private final List<Car> cars ;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, Car...cars) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            this.cars = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(cars));
        }

        public List<Car> getCars() {
            return cars ;
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

which renders as

[image]

Comment: Thank you everything works but somehow some Entries in the Table are now duplicated

Comment: @MNCODE They are duplicated in the example application I posted?

Comment: No in my Implementation in my Project

Comment: @MNCODE So presumably there is something wrong with your implementation...

Comment: Okay made some more Tests on my Project and the Problem is not coming from this awnser sorry, It was a Hibernate Bug with JPA